# Unity 3D, Compiz effects and Intel Sandybridge Mobile Graphics

Tags: 11.10, unity, compiz, ati, intel-graphics

My notebook is a Pavilion dv6-6030el with an Intel i7-2630QM CPU, 8 GB of RAM and the ATI HD 6490m as VGA dedicated. I was forced to stop it due to the switchable graphics issue editing the GRUB and rc.local files, so right now the notebook is running with the only Intel Sandybridge Mobile graphics chip (I've earned something like +400% of battery life after this trick), I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity 3D, X.Org Intel drivers and Mesa drivers are installed but I can't make Compiz and advanced graphics effects to work. I've seen many videos on YouTube with older and worser VGA running Compiz at full capabilities while here the "Experience" rate is only "Standard". I've installed also the CompizConfig Settings Manager but I can't even change the size of the Unity Dash icons.

Thanks for your attention, I'm looking forward for any kind of help :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a similar problem with HP Pavilion dv7, 8GB RAM, AMD Radeon HD 6700M Series.

While I haven't found a solution, here's what I've learned:

- Don't try install the proprietary drivers. You get errors trying to do it, and various screen errors happen, such as blank screens.
- You may have power consumption issues with the Radeon card enabled
  The integrated Intel display card is fine for 2D graphics.
- Many others recommend only using 2D if the video card is ATI.
- Many others are experiencing similar issues with laptops that have switchable
  graphics

I hope somebody comes out with a good fix for the laptop video driver issues, or at least makes it very clear in the install process "don't try to get the 3D working with your HW configuration" and remove the indicator to install the proprietary ATI drivers if switchable graphics is enabled.